# Why can't I define a variable inside a for loop in this way?

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors

Through a test I found out that,

This is not legal :

```
for (int i= 0; i < 1000000000; i++) 
    int j = i & i+1 ; // j cannot be declared here!
```

but this is :

```
for (int i= 0; i < 1000000000; i++) { 
    int j = i & i+1 ;
}
```

Why?

Comment: aren't both the loops exactly same?

Comment: @dreamer- They should be, but not. The first one doesn't compile!

Comment: @ZouZou- So Rohit's answer completely makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, sure, blame everything on Eclipse!

Comment: @HotLicks - An edit has been done on the question that is not visible now, and indeed it was fault of Eclipse :)

Comment: @HotLicks- sometimes comments are misleading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first way is not legal, as it is clear to the compiler that you can't use `j` that you declared there, as you can't have another statement inside that `for` loop. Basically the new declaration of variable at that place will go out of scope the very next statement, thus is not doing any good.

While in the second case, the loop is followed by braces, which creates a new scope, and you can use the variable.

Comment: What is the difference in those loops? I cannot see any...

Comment: @Szymon: one uses curly braces, which allows a new scope for variables. The other one doesn't.

Comment: Very wise :) seems rational for me

Comment: Yes... it makes sense. `{}` = many lines hence `j` _maybe_ used later. But without it it has no use later ==> _unnecessary_ declaration.

Comment: First I thought is's about scope.

Comment: @mok You were right. It's about scope only.

Comment: Oh wait, but we can use `int j = i & i+1 + (j - 3);` in the loop

Comment: is it specified in the language specification somewhere? or some kind of check that compiler does to make sure that its disallowed as the variable goes out of scope immediatly

Comment: @mok Certainly not. You can't use `j` there, as it has not been fully initialized.

Comment: @mok don't get confused (read my comment). It is valid in the loop with the braces.

Comment: @dreamer Yes it is. Don't know why, but JLS is not opening on my machine (strange), else I would have added the appropriate section.

Comment: well, not only Java, its failing to compile using `gcc` also in C program :)

Comment: @ambigram_maker could you point out the line number in the above link where its mentioned

Comment: I've studied compiler design on B.Sc. but now I'm wondering about what they are capable of.

Comment: I think listing disassembly here is really an overkill or even misleading. The problem here is purely a parsing rule and not the compiler trying to be "clever" and rejecting variable declarations that cannot be used. In fact most Java compilers are not optimizing ones and would happily spit out byte code exactly matching the source. It will be the runtime (with JIT) that notices the loop body does nothing and optimize the whole thing away.

Comment: What is pointed out in this answer is wrong. A statement can be legally compiled in thousands of bytecodes and still be considered as one.

Comment: @Jack Ah! You're right. That was completely misleading :( I've removed that part, but the baseline of my answer still stands.

Comment: Declaring but not using variables is not illegal, as can be seen in the second case where the declaration is merely included in a block. The compiler will detect the un-used variable in the block too, and will output a warning about that if configured to do so. Thus, I think your argument does not hold and the explanation is not correct.

Comment: @HannoBinder May be I've not explained it very clearly, but the point is, the variable declared in first loop cannot be used in any way. For that the braces needs to be added. So as it stands, the newly declared variable is of no use.

Comment: Why isn't it just removed by compiler optimization instead of refusing to compile?

Answer (score 17):

A local variable declaration needs to be in a block.  In the first case, you don't have it in a block.  In the second case, `j` is within a block, so it is legal.

The local variable declaration isn't a statement, it is a *local variable declaration statement*.  From the reference below, a local variable declaration can appear only as a statement within a block.  (A block is a pair of curly braces containing statements and declarations.)

```
for (int i= 0; i < 1000000000; i++) 
    int j = i & i+1 ; // Local variable j declaration not within a block ==> ERROR


for (int i= 0; i < 1000000000; i++) { 
    int j = i & i+1 ; // Local variable j declaration within a block ==> NO ERROR
}
```

---

Quoting from [14.4. Local Variable Declaration Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4):

> ...
>
> **Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by
>   a block.** Local variable declaration statements may be intermixed
>   freely with other kinds of statements in the block.
>
> ...

And from [14.2. Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2):

> **A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and
>   local variable declaration statements within braces.**
>
> ```
>  Block:
>    { BlockStatementsopt }
>
>  BlockStatements:
>    BlockStatement
>    BlockStatements BlockStatement
>
>  BlockStatement:
>    LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
>    ClassDeclaration
>    Statement
> ```
>
> A block is executed by executing each of the local variable
>   declaration statements and other statements in order from first to
>   last (left to right). If all of these block statements complete
>   normally, then the block completes normally. If any of these block
>   statements complete abruptly for any reason, then the block completes
>   abruptly for the same reason.

---

Moreover, this behavior isn't quite limited to Java.  You'd observe an error in a similar situation even in C:

```
for(int i=0; i<=100; i++)
  int j = i;     /* Error: error: expected expression before 'int' */

for(int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
  int j = i;     /* Perfect */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems this is the official ref., now how do you apply this to this for statement?

Comment: @mok Added some explanation to the top.

Comment: Really good. _"A block is a pair of curly braces containing statements and declarations"._ I thought for,while,... are blocks, you mean they aren't, don't you?

Comment: @mok Without a pair of curly braces, those aren't.

Comment: @mok The JLS definition is actually that a `{}` block itself is a kind of statement.

Comment: So this is really a good example of semantic error check in compilers.

Comment: @mok Also highlighted the relevant section that defines what a block is.  Moreover, as you might notice in the edit, similar declarations would also produce an error in C.

Answer (score 4):

A local variable declaration isn't allowed as a single statement for any of the grammatical constructs that allow for a single statement instead of a block. So `for`, `while`, `if`, etc...

The way it breaks down is (paraphrased a bit), you have the [`for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1):

> for ( ... ; ... ; ... ) Statement

Where [`Statement` can include](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5):

> - Block
> - ExpressionStatement

An [`ExpressionStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) is what you can use when you only have the single statement but a [`LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) is only a [`BlockStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2).

As @RohitJain has pointed out it wouldn't be particularly useful to only have a variable declaration as the single statement of a loop.

Comment: Good extension to while,if,... .