# Java, declare a variable in an if statement without curly braces

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with this code:

```
if (false)
  int i = 9;
...
```

I realize it's useless, cause the scope of the if statement would comprise only the declaration and I wouldn't be reachable after its declaration cause it would be out of scope, and perhaps the compiler is smart enough to avoid this situation. If I include the curly braces, everything works, perhaps because the compiler knows that I could write more code after the declaration and use the variable in that code.
I'm just wondering, is it really this why I'm getting a compile-time error or is there a deeper explanation?
I'm getting:

```
A.java:4: '.class' expected
      int i = 4;
          ^
A.java:4: not a statement
      int i = 4;
      ^
A.java:4: illegal start of expression
      int i = 4;
            ^
A.java:4: ';' expected
      int i = 4;
             ^
4 errors
```

Thanks in advance,
Alessandro

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22576042/2235132) might also help.

Comment: The short answer is that a local variable declaration needs to be in a __block__.  When you don't put parenthesis, it's not the case.  Hence the error.

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone!I'm preparing for the OCA certification and with your answears (also to other questions!) I'm learning a lot of useful things, not only for the exam!

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the Java specification about [Local Variable Declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4):

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block. Local variable declaration statements may be intermixed freely with other kinds of statements in the block.

This was one answer as pointed out by [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22576042/2235132)s comment.