# What's difference between removeing brackets with add brackets in for statements in java

Tags: java

I hava try below code in my project.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
            Integer k = new Integer(i);//ERROR
        System.out.println("Hello Word");
    }
}
```

However,This snippet can NOT be compiled caused by this line:
*Integer k = new Integer(i);*

and
chage from

```
Integer k = new Integer(i);
```

to

```
{Integer k = new Integer(i);}
```

this snippet will OK

## My Question:

What's difference between **Integer k = new Integer(i);** and **{Integer k = new Integer(i);}** under my code snippet?

Thanks

Comment: and what is "ERROR" ?

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept it. If you are still in question let me know and I will clarify things for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575906/2218253)

Your initial declaration goes out of scope each time the loop loops, making it useless.

The brackets create a new scope.

**scope definition**

> Scope refers to the lifetime and accessibility of a variable. How
>   large the scope is depends on where a variable is declared. For
>   example, if a variable is declared at the top of a class then it will
>   accessible to all of the class methods. If it’s declared in a method
>   then it can only be used in that method.

[Here](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-variable-scope/) is a great example of scope and out of scope

```
// Demonstrate block scope.
class Scope {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
  int n1; // Visible in main

  n1 = 10;

  if(n1 == 10)
   {
   // start new scope
   int n2 = 20; // visible only to this block

   // num1 and num2 both visible here.
   System.out.println("n1 and n2 : "+ n1 +""+ n2);
   }
   // n2 = 100; // Error! y not known here

   // n1 is still visible here.
    System.out.println("n1 is " + n1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Java spec, You cannot declare a local variable when there is no scope. While declaring Integer k = new Integer(i) in for, there is no scope. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html

> A local variable, one of the following
>   *A local variable declared in a block
>   *A local variable declared in a for statement

Answer (score 0):

**Variable declaration is not allowed!** Because the scope of your variable is not determined. So, if you add brackets, your variable will be scoped as *local* in your `for` loop.